# How to update timestamp value in every doc in an Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

```
    _source": {
"_timestamp": 1338859632,
"cpu_percent": 65
}
```

I have docs in the format above in my Elasticsearch index. I would like to multiply "_timestamp" values by 1000 (sec to milli seconds).

There is also a mapping that "_timestamp" is in date time format.

How can I do the above operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `update_by_query`:

```json
POST datesample/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['_timestamp'] = ctx._source['_timestamp'] * 1000L",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm getting a runtime error after trying the above. Any suggestion?

Comment: Let me be more clear. "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "failed to parse field [_timestamp] of type [date] in document with id 'G-CUTn8Bb7ON-LcciHNw'. Preview of field's value: 'ctx._source._timestamp * 1000L'"

Comment: @AdityaVashist can you please add index mapping in question.